# How to make an application available for particular device?

Tags: android, google-play

My users complain that my android application is not available in Google Play for particular device - Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro.

What should I check (and where) to make it available?

**AndroidManifest.xml** part related to permissions and features:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.rosspam"
    android:versionCode="19"
    android:versionName="1.6.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application ...>

        ...

        <receiver android:name="org.myapp.SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        ...

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html carefully, you will get your answer.

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml (or at least the section related to permissions and features plus the SDK versions min/target etc).

Comment: @Squonk, updated the question with AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: @LA_ : Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions which is about features requested implicitly when requesting certain permissions. My guess is it's related to the SMS permissions you're requesting. As Emanuel Selbold suggests in his answer you can set `android:required="false" if necessary but you'll need to modify your code to first check to see if a device has 'telephony' capability or not. Thos that don't would still be able to install your app but not use the SMS code. I can't see any other permissions which would imply features

Comment: @LA_ : Actually `READ_PHONE_STATE` is also another potential candidate for implicit feature requirements. I'd suspect your app isn't available to a lot of devices such as tablets which don't have "phone" capability - that would probably include my Nexus 7 (2013 version) which only has wifi.

Answer (score 0):

First, check in android developer console whether you disclosed/removed some devices there - check under APK. You also should check in your Manifest.xml for the right values of android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

1. Sign into your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Click on All Applications and click on the application whose device availability you'd like to view.
3. After that, click on APK.
4. After that, under Current APK, click on the link labeled See Supported Devices

Source: [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017?hl=en)

Also, some devices aren't able to download because you specified (for example) a `minSdkVersion` of 16 and the device which wants to access is only on Gingerbread 2.3.3 API 10.

Or if you wrote in the manifest, your app urgently **needs** a big screen, some device won't be able to see it in the store, because the device is against the requirements of your app.

Comment: Thanks. `Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 12.2` is in the list and marked as supported, `minSdkVersion` is 7.

Comment: Is the Device which wants to download the app stock or rooted/modified? Have you got any restricting changes in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @LA_ : Do you know for definite which model(s) of the Tab Pro your users are unable to download your app to? There are actually 7 different models of the Tab Pro which include 3 different screen sizes and some have 3G capability and others only wi-fi.

Answer (score 0):

Nono no, it's not only the SDK. Check if the Device allows ALL your permissions. If you want to have some permissions which are optional you can use use-features like

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
```

Means. SDK AND Permissions must match.